# Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

Tags: java, string, class, static

My code compiles fine but when I go to run it, it gives me the error:

```
`Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]`
```

Here is my code:

```
class Employee{
  private String name; //name reference field
  private int idNumber; //integer variable holding employee's ID number
  private String department; //holds the name of the employees department
  private String position; //holds the name of the employee's position in the department
  //the following is the first required constructor
  //using the terms n,i,d, and p to assign values to the above fields
  public Employee(String n, int i, String d, String p){
    name=n;
    idNumber=i;
    department=d;
    position=p;
  }
  //the following is a constructor that sets the fields blank to be filled in
  public Employee(){
    name="";
    idNumber=0;
    department="";
    position="";
  }
  //writing appropriate accessor and mutator methods for all the fields
  public void setName(String n){ name=n; }
  public void setIdNumber(int i){ idNumber = i; }
  public void setDepartment(String d){ department = d; }
  public void setPosition(String p){ position = p; }
  public String getName(){ return name; }
  public int getIdNumber(){ return idNumber; }
  public String getDepartment(){ return department; }
  public String getPosition(){ return position; }
}
//new program creating employee objects
public class EmployeeInfo 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //create an Employee object
    Employee employee1 = new Employee("Susan Meyers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President");
    //test the accessor methods
    System.out.println("***employee1***");
    System.out.println("Name: " + employee1.getName());
    System.out.println("ID number: " + employee1.getIdNumber());
    System.out.println("Department: " + employee1.getDepartment());
    System.out.println("Position: " + employee1.getPosition());
    //create another Employee object
    Employee employee2 = new Employee();
    //test the mutator methods
    employee2.setName("Mark Jones");
    employee2.setIdNumber(39119);
    employee2.setDepartment("IT");
    employee2.setPosition("Programmer");
    System.out.println("\n***employee2***");
    System.out.println("Name: " + employee2.getName());
    System.out.println("ID number: " + employee2.getIdNumber());
    System.out.println("Department: " + employee2.getDepartment());
    System.out.println("Position: " + employee2.getPosition());
    //create another Employee object
    Employee employee3 = new Employee();
    //test the mutator methods
    employee2.setName("Joy Rogers");
    employee2.setIdNumber(81774);
    employee2.setDepartment("Manufacturing");
    employee2.setPosition("Engineer");
    System.out.println("\n***employee3***");
    System.out.println("Name: " + employee3.getName());
    System.out.println("ID number: " + employee3.getIdNumber());
    System.out.println("Department: " + employee3.getDepartment());
    System.out.println("Position: " + employee3.getPosition());
  }
}
```

I know I need to add the "public static void main(String[] args)" command somewhere but i'm not sure where!
Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: You've already got a `main` in `EmployeeInfo`.  How are you trying to run  it?  (I can run your code and it works fine for me)

Comment: I'm using Dr.Java and I have the file saved as a .JAVA file on a USB drive with the name EmployeeInfo. I press compile and no issue, press run and I get that one error.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different class
Employee and EmployeeInfo
I am assuming you are trying to execute Employee class where compiler unable to find Public static void main

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should compile all '.java' file. You can do that using command line as

```
javac *.java
```

Secondly you should run class which has 'main' method. As

```
java EmployeeInfo
```